# Java Spring boot issues with static/non-static methods in checking paypal subscribe code

Tags: java, spring-boot, paypal, static, static-methods

I am working on a Java Springboot application and I am trying to integrate paypal subsciption.

I have this code working as an api to do a check on the subscribe code. But I want to use this function to do an internal check inside another end point.

```java
package com.rom.paypal;
    
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.paypal.api.payments.Links;
import com.paypal.api.payments.Payment;
import com.paypal.base.rest.APIContext;
import com.paypal.base.rest.OAuthTokenCredential;
import com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalRESTException;
import com.rom.controller.utils.AppMessageLocalUtil;
import com.rom.model.BaseResponse;
import com.rom.repo.PersonRepo;
import com.rom.service.impl.ImageServiceImpl;
import org.bson.assertions.Assertions;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.http.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Controller
public class PaypalController {
    @Value("${paypal.client.id}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${paypal.client.secret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Value("${paypal.host}")
    private String host;

    @Autowired
    PaypalService service;

    @Autowired
    private final AppMessageLocalUtil appMessageLocalUtil;

    PaypalController(AppMessageLocalUtil appMessageLocalUtil) {
        this.appMessageLocalUtil = appMessageLocalUtil;
    }

    private String generateAccessToken() throws PayPalRESTException {
        Map<String, String> configurationMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        configurationMap.put("service.EndPoint",
                host);
        OAuthTokenCredential merchantTokenCredential = new OAuthTokenCredential(
                clientId, clientSecret, configurationMap);
        return merchantTokenCredential.getAccessToken();
    }


    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping("/api/showsubscriptiondetails")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<BaseResponse> showSubscriptionDetails(
            @RequestParam("subscriptionID") String subscriptionID
    ) throws PayPalRESTException {
        BaseResponse response = new BaseResponse();
        //String subscriptionCode = "I-CBACCTR68N9W";

        String bearerToken = generateAccessToken();
        String token = bearerToken.split(" ")[1].trim();

        WebClient client = WebClient.create(host);

        WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec = client.get()
                .uri("/v1/billing/subscriptions/"+subscriptionID+"?fields=plan")
                .headers(h -> {
                    h.setBearerAuth(token);
                })
                .retrieve();

        String responseBody = responseSpec.bodyToMono(String.class).block();

        System.out.println("responseBody-- "+ responseBody);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode root = null;
        try {
            root = mapper.readTree(responseBody);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JsonNode status = root.path("status");
        JsonNode plan = root.path("plan").get("name");
        System.out.println(status);
        System.out.println(plan);

        BasicDBObject res = new BasicDBObject();
        res.put("status", status);
        res.put("plan", plan);

        response.setCode("OK");
        response.setData(res);
        response.setDescription(appMessageLocalUtil.getLanguageMessage("subscription.found"));
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(response);
    }
}
```

I want to run this as a function inside another end point - when obtaining the subscribe code and doing a check on it to get more information on its status.

```java
ResponseEntity<BaseResponse> res = PaypalController.showSubscriptionDetails(subscriptionID);
System.out.println("res " + res);
```

I am running into a build error relating to static and non-static methods - and I am unsure how to resolve this. I have two parts to the subscribe api with paypal - generating a token from the client, secret -- and then the actual check itself on the code.

```java
@CrossOrigin
@PutMapping("/api/account/subscription")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<BaseResponse> editSubscription (
        @RequestHeader("Authorization") String bearerToken,
        @RequestParam("subscriptionID") String subscriptionID) throws PayPalRESTException {
    BaseResponse response = new BaseResponse();
    //get logged in user
    System.out.println("xxxxxx bearerToken "+ bearerToken);
    String email = tokenHandler.getEmailFromBearerToken(bearerToken);
    System.out.println("xxxxxemail "+ email);
    System.out.println("subscriptionID " + subscriptionID);

    ResponseEntity<BaseResponse> res = PaypalController.showSubscriptionDetails(subscriptionID);
    System.out.println("res " + res);
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("email").is(email));

    List<Person> px = MongoApp.mongoOps().find(query, Person.class);
    System.out.println("xxxxxxp "+ px);

    String loggedId = "-1";
    if (!px.isEmpty()) {
        for (Person person : px) {
            loggedId = person.getId();
        }
    }
    //MongoApp.mongoOps().updateFirst(query(where("id").is("60acbbda484efb5c54add242")), update("age", age), Person.class);
    //Person p = MongoApp.mongoOps().findOne(query(where("id").is("60acbbda484efb5c54add242")), Person.class);
    try {
        Person p = MongoApp.mongoOps().findById(loggedId, Person.class);

        p.setUpdatedAt(new Date());
        p.setSubscriptionID(subscriptionID);

        if (p != null) {
            personRepo.save(p);
        }

        response.setCode("OK");
        response.setDescription(appMessageLocalUtil.getLanguageMessage("operation.complete"));
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(response);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        response.setCode("500");
        response.setDescription(appMessageLocalUtil.getLanguageMessage("internal.server.error"));
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .body(response);
    }
}
```

### 21st April 2023

I've only managed to get it working with an empty constructor - and invoking it as a new instance -- but I've had to push environment variables at this level - rather than having the PaypalService class acquire them from within. Whenever I try and get the function to use environment variables they come out null?

```
PaypalService paypalService = new PaypalService();
BasicDBObject res =  paypalService.showSubscriptionDetails(host, clientId, clientSecret, subscriptionID);
```

Comment: "I am running into a build error relating to static and non-static methods" - precisely what errors are you getting?  Please show us the compilation error messages.

Comment: that is the error - it wants me to turn everything in PaypalController.showSubscriptionDetails(subscriptionID) -- into static methods - but then it doesnt get the token and is unable to proceed getting the subscribe token check

Comment: I have managed to get it working - but I can't seem to gain access to environment application.properties variables inside the "showSubscriptionDetails" itself - its like I have to pass everything through to the function in order for it to consume the constants